# Cargar fecha en input

Tags: html

Estoy realizando un formulario y para insertar la fecha y enviarla no tengo problema. El problema viene cuando intento meterle una fecha manualmente desde js, no se carga.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el código del input:

```
<input class="form-control datetimepicker" type="date" id="fecha_nacimiento" name="fecha_nacimiento"/>
```

Y adjunto el código del JS:

```
$('#fecha_nacimiento').val(fecha_nacimiento);
```

Siendo fecha nacimiento un valor del estilo: 01/01/1990.

¿Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Prueba con la fecha “1990-01-01”, el formato del valor del campo fecha siempre debe ser yyyy-mm-dd ([fuente](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/date)) incluso aunque luego visualmente se represente de otra manera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar al formato en ingles del input.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {          $('#fecha_nacimiento').val('2013-12-31');
                                
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input class="form-control datetimepicker" type="date" id="fecha_nacimiento" name="fecha_nacimiento"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Puedes mirar aquí también
[Setting format and value in date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770615/setting-format-and-value-in-input-type-date)

Comment: Perfecto, justo lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias.